# Sharing system to my remote friend via Internet

Tags: php

I have my system created by using PHP, MySQLi, HTML, CSS and JavaScript and  installed it in a localhost XAMPP sever.

I need to share my system via the Internet to my friends. I have no domain name or other online server.

What can I do for free to complete sharing of my system?

Comment: You're going to have a hard time routing anything to a device on your home network without a static IP address, which is not something that is typically included for household internet packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngrok ( https://ngrok.com/ ) to create a tunnel to your localhost. After you install the package You can run `./ngrok http port`, like, `./ngrok http 8080` and you would get a url which you can share with the world.

like this:

> http://ec13044d.ngrok.io -> localhost:8080

However, you need to create an account at Ngrok [and select Free plan].